# Unable to play sound with AudioPlayer package

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to play a sound from my asset directory in dart, I have added the required lines of code and also included the asset directory in pubspec.yaml.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();

                  player.play(DeviceFileSource('note1.wav'));
                },
                child: Text('Click Me'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the source of the audio by using `AssetSource()` and make sure to add the source of your audio in the yaml file

```
onPressed: () {
    AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
    player.play(AssetSource('audio.mp3'));
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AssetSource for this because as per the documentation of AudioPlayer:

1. **DeviceFileSource**: [is used to] access a file in the user's device, probably selected by a file picker
2. **AssetSource**: [is used to] play an asset bundled with your app, normally within the `assets` directory

Don't worry, this gave me some grief too and the answer above pointed me in the right direction. I just wanted to take an extra step to understand why, hope this helps!